# Java Concurrency in Practice "Listing 15.7. Insertion in the Michael-Scott nonblocking queue algorithm (Michael and Scott, 1996)."

Tags: java, multithreading, nonblocking, compare-and-swap

I am reading *Java Concurrency in Practice* and encounter [15.7 Insertion in the Michael-Scott nonblocking queue algorithm.](http://jcip.net/listings/LinkedQueue.java).

```
package net.jcip.examples;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

import net.jcip.annotations.*;

/**
 * LinkedQueue
 * <p/>
 * Insertion in the Michael-Scott nonblocking queue algorithm
 *
 * @author Brian Goetz and Tim Peierls
 */
@ThreadSafe
public class LinkedQueue <E> {

    private static class Node <E> {
        final E item;
        final AtomicReference<LinkedQueue.Node<E>> next;

        public Node(E item, LinkedQueue.Node<E> next) {
            this.item = item;
            this.next = new AtomicReference<LinkedQueue.Node<E>>(next);
        }
    }

    private final LinkedQueue.Node<E> dummy = new LinkedQueue.Node<E>(null, null);
    private final AtomicReference<LinkedQueue.Node<E>> head
            = new AtomicReference<LinkedQueue.Node<E>>(dummy);
    private final AtomicReference<LinkedQueue.Node<E>> tail
            = new AtomicReference<LinkedQueue.Node<E>>(dummy);

    public boolean put(E item) {
        LinkedQueue.Node<E> newNode = new LinkedQueue.Node<E>(item, null);
        while (true) {
            LinkedQueue.Node<E> curTail = tail.get();
            LinkedQueue.Node<E> tailNext = curTail.next.get();
            if (curTail == tail.get()) { // what is the purpose of this check?
                if (tailNext != null) {
                    // Queue in intermediate state, advance tail
                    tail.compareAndSet(curTail, tailNext);
                } else {
                    // In quiescent state, try inserting new node
                    if (curTail.next.compareAndSet(null, newNode)) {
                        // Insertion succeeded, try advancing tail
                        tail.compareAndSet(curTail, newNode);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If we have `if (curTail == tail.get())` check, we can find out whether `tail` has been changed after `LinkedQueue.Node<E> curTail = tail.get();`, if `tail` has been changed, execute `while` loop again. But if we omit this check and `tail` has been changed after `LinkedQueue.Node<E> curTail = tail.get();`, we will fail in `tail.compareAndSet(curTail, tailNext);` or `curTail.next.compareAndSet(null, newNode)`, we will execute `while` loop again, **so the result is the same as having the check**.

**So, are there other differences between having or not having this check? Can we just omit this check?**

Comment: The difference looks to be the second argument - I would imagine that compareAndSet with `tailNext` is rather very different from calling the _next_ element's compareAndSet with an already built `newNode`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans But if `tail` has been changed, both `compareAndSet`s will return false.

Comment: @JasonLaw `compareAndSet` will return false, but it will contiune the loop until **false**. Having this check looks like **fail-fast**. Once `currTail` is not real tail, the following is useless

Comment: @Tttttsing fail-fast is the only reason I can think of.